# outputting a message on Aplication launch screen, but only want it to apear on first viewing of this page (java)

Tags: java, user-interface, homescreen

I have a GUI application on the initial launch screen the user is prompted to enter their name like so

```
String uName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name to contine");
    myUser.setName(uName);
```

This is Stored in a global instance of the user data class to be used later in the program. My application also features a home button on every page. like so;

```
 private void homeBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    HomeGUI myHome = new HomeGUI();
    myHome.setVisible(true);

    this.dispose();
}
```

MY problem is every time the user hits the home button to get back they are re-prompted to enter their name. how can i code this so the Program only asks for the users name once, on the first launch of the application?

Answer (score 2):

> MY problem is every time the user hits the home button to get back
>   they are re-prompted to enter their name. how can i code this so the
>   Program only asks for the users name once, on the first launch of the
>   application?

This is happening because there is no checking wheather the name is already present in **Global Parameter** or Not

Put a `check` on the line before asking the Name from User

```
if(myUser.getName()==null || myUser.getName()==""){
String uName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name to contine");
    myUser.setName(uName);
 }
```

**Some suggestion**  :

I prefer to use Google Guava Library's [Strings](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html)  class's  method `isNullOrEmpty()`

See it's beauty ,As the name suggest it checks for both Null Or Empty String in one condition

```
Boolean check=Strings.isNullOrEmpty(testString);
```

Comment: Great thank you , yes so simple now that i think of it!!

Answer (score 0):

Before prompting user to enter name, just check myUser is already set or not. If it is set, do nothing else prompt user.